# Pulse sensor issues and How to get -5V from Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage, infrared, light-sensor, photosensor

So I'm trying to [make a pulse sensor using TCRT5000](http://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/%7Estallur/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Heart-Rate-Measurement-using-PPG1.pdf) IR sensor and arduino UNO (giving out 4.8V really from 5V pin) (Baud Rate 19200), and I'm supposed to get a pulse plot like this

[image: Ideal pulse curve]

But I'm getting it like this
[image: curves attained]

As you can see, absolutely no pulse is noticeable.

Below is the schematic
[image: Schematic]

Below are some essential points:

1. In the phototransistor stage, I don't understand the symbol with the Arrow on the extreme left, I thought it was a Pot set to 1K Ohm so I used a 1K resistor between the 150 Ohm resistor and +5V.
2. My 1uF capacitor in the second stage is tantalum. My second capacitor, the 4.7uF, is electrolytic.
3. The schematic says the pin 11 of the LM324 should be connected to -5V, since I don't know how to get -5V out of Arduino I just connected it to GND on Arduino.
4. I did not have a IN4004 diode so I used a IN4007.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I see dozens of pulses. Maybe try lowering the timebase to get a better resolution.

Comment: @Andyaka time base? Baudrate u mean?

Comment: 1- it is an adjustable resistor or pot. 2- ok. 3- You can get a negative voltage driving PWM a doubler inverter made with diodes-capacitors. You can use 1 or 2 output pins for that. 4- it is ok... LM324 is not a rail to rail opamp.

Comment: @Antonio51 So basically where I've gone wrong is connecting Pin 11 to GND when it should be to -5V? Please elaborate in layman terms that PWM point, have heard of it the first time. If possible please give a step by step instruction, I'm not educated well in electronics.

Comment: @Antonio51 if they are already using a pot, why use the 150Ohm also? Why not set the pot to 1150 Ohm?

Comment: Pot can be inadvertently set to 0 ... Diode of TCRT should not "like" this.

Comment: That's not a "Pot set to 1K Ohm" it's a 1k pot used as a variable resistor, which you adjust to a value which makes the circuit work. Your would typically start by setting it somewhere in the middle of its range and adjusting it higher or lower as required.

Comment: @brhans yeah I figured that too and used a pot, now I have some semblance of the expected results, waiting now for my voltage inverter to arrive so I can properly power my Op amp and get this thing resolved.

Comment: I see you have also deleted most of the content of your question here, as you did in another post. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @PStechPaul because only part of my question got answered. The other part I have asked on another forum now. There were two questions, one didn't get answered. In fact I have found a better solution to even the question which remains, which I think I should post in the answers.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to invalidate previous answers. I've rolled back your question to the form that was answered.

Comment: @Hearth, sure, perhaps I'll post the solution to the first question as well which I arrived at through help at another forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a negative voltage, you can use this (only V2- part of schematic, D2-D3-C10-C11) or use outputs of Arduino with software ...

[image]

Comment: I was thinking it might be easier to get -5v using an adaptor or a battery, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can ... for testing. Do not forget to add decoupling 100 nF for -5 V near supply pin to ground.

Comment: Antonio51 has given the right solution, but I found to my application the use of a TC7660 IC more suitable with 10uF Capacitor (as advised on another forum). But since Antonio's answer is correct and the source for my further inquiry, that stays as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question first part, the ideal method needs to be to check the output of each stage progressively and make alterations till that expected output is achieved. It was discovered that 1K pot was not set at 1K and needed to be altered to receive the expected output at stage 1. In this case the 1k pot needed to be turned to zero.